# Defining function inside class and using it outside of the class

Tags: python

For a game I am working on I have made a class and within my class I have created a function. However, when I try to call this function outside of the class it shows an error.

The game creates targets using turtle and counts hits and misses when the user clicks the target or the background.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

    def deletescore():
        global score
        score -= 1

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Reflex Aim Training")
screen.bgcolor("grey")
screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())

screen.mainloop()
```

The game window opens but when I try to click on the window (which would normally count as a miss and take 1 from my score) I recieve an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
    fun(x, y)
  File "I:\My Drive\flowtest.py", line 279, in <lambda>
    screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())
NameError: name 'deletescore' is not defined
```

Comment: Why put it in the class at all if it's not interacting with the class/instance in any way?

Comment: You need an instance of `Application`, e.g. `app = Application(...)` and then call `app.deletescore`

Comment: Wny are you using a `lambda` function that doesn't refer to any of its arguments? It looks like you want `screen.onclick(screen.deletescore)`, but we can't know without seeing how your `Frame` class works.

Answer (score 2):

use `Application.deletescore()`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function outside the class and then add to it.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

def deletescore(self):
    global score
    score -= 1

Application.deletescore = deletescore
```

Then you can use it. Pay attention to the self parameter. A class method normally operates on the class instance unless used in a "static way" as in this example.

Comment: I did what you said however I am getting a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "I:\My Drive\testvalidate.py", line 276, in <lambda>
    screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())
TypeError: deletescore() missing 1 required positional argum

Comment: Try without self in the declaration of deletescore